# Android nativeLoad crash

Tags: android, crash, java-native-interface, loadlibrary

Our app has millions of user, and we have encountered one wicked crash problem when we try to load our private so in a worker thread, about 0.01% of our users will crash during System.load(). 
Log like:

```
608dd000-608de000 r--p 00000000 b3:07 8514       /data/data/com.UCMobile/com/core/version.0/lib/libWebCore_UC.so
Thread Name: '<unregistered>'
pid: 16879, tid: 16947  >>> com.UCMobile <<<
signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR), fault addr 61e3eb64
 r0 61e3eb64  r1 00000000  r2 00000480  r3 c0000000
 r4 00000000  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
 r8 000e7094  r9 00000005  10 6110a000  fp 0000006b
 ip 00000000  sp 60bec8c8  lr 00000000  pc 40062698  cpsr a0000010

     #00   pc  40062698  /system/bin/linker
     #01   pc  40061ce0  /system/bin/linker
     #02   pc  4005fc22  /system/bin/linker
     #03   pc  40060172  /system/bin/linker
     #04   pc  400614fe  /system/bin/linker
     #05   pc  0006755c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #06   pc  00091f68  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #07   pc  000273a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #08   pc  0002b2dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #09   pc  00084e44  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #10   pc  00093f98  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #11   pc  000273a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #12   pc  0002b2dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #13   pc  00084a94  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #14   pc  00084b20  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #15   pc  000700f8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #16   pc  0000e4a4  /system/lib/libc.so

     >>> [Dalvik stack info] <<<
     at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:339)
     at java.lang.System.load(System.java:500)
```

And when we looked into linker's code, we figured out the line of code where app crashed:
http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/bionic/linker/linker_phdr.cpp#348

```
bool ElfReader::LoadSegments() {

347    if ((phdr->p_flags & PF_W) != 0 && PAGE_OFFSET(seg_file_end) > 0) {
348      memset((void*)seg_file_end, 0, PAGE_SIZE - PAGE_OFFSET(seg_file_end));   --> crash when memset
349    }
350
```

In most cases, fault addr is equal to "seg_file_end". (We can verify it by the info of `readelf -l libWebCore_UC.so`.)
And if one user crashed like these, he will crash again and again. (some users crashed hundreds of times.)

And we have checked so's size before we loaded it, its size must be the same as we expect.

Most of these kind of crash is sigbus, sometimes is SIGSEGV.
Anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: "he will crash again and again" - does uninstall and fresh install help?

Comment: Yes, `adb shell pm clear com.UCMobile` seems to help too.

Comment: This problem might be result of so corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to code from the Linux kernel:

```
int filemap_fault(struct vm_area_struct *vma, struct vm_fault *vmf)
{
    int error;
    struct file *file = vma->vm_file;
    struct address_space *mapping = file->f_mapping;
    struct file_ra_state *ra = &file->f_ra;
    struct inode *inode = mapping->host;
    pgoff_t offset = vmf->pgoff;
    struct page *page;
    loff_t size;
    int ret = 0;

    size = round_up(i_size_read(inode), PAGE_SIZE);
    if (offset >= size >> PAGE_SHIFT)
        return VM_FAULT_SIGBUS;
...
    /* Things didn't work out. Return zero to tell the mm layer so. */
    shrink_readahead_size_eio(file, ra);
    return VM_FAULT_SIGBUS;
}
```

It has two failure situations. One of them is that the file size is not large enough to cover the vma, the other is reading from filesystem has failed.

And you should ask me before posting this.